# Position a list at the bottom of it's containing element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position a `<ul>` at the bottom of it's containing `<div>` using `position:absolute`  I am not quite sure what I am missing, but the list is not appearing and when I inspect the element it looks like it is at the top of the containing element.

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #BFBFBF
}

.list-container {
    background-color: grey;
    position: relative;
}

ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="list-container">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h2>Heading</h2>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The .list-container doesn't have a height as it doesn't contain any elements (but for the absolutely positioned ul) and it's positioned at the top of the .container. The absolutely positioned ul has a bottom: 0 making the Heading text occur above the .container

Comment: @ckuijjer I think I get it now.  The list-container div contains the ul, but the ul is absolutely positioned and out of the document flow.  And that would be why the .list-container div needs a height.

Comment: That's exactly the issue! I think you might even think of combining the .container and the .list-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a height to the list-container, not to container.

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #BFBFBF;
}

.list-container {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="list-container">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h2>Heading</h2>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I wasn't sure about the height, I guess I thought applying it on the parent div would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You were not setting the size of containing division.

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #BFBFBF
}

.list-container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: grey;
    position: relative;
}

ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="list-container">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h2>Hello</h2>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't realize that it had to be on the .list-container div instead of the parent.